# How to detect if another app floating button is on top of our application?

Tags: java, android, nativescript, detection, floating-action-button

I want to know is there any way to recognizing that an app floating button is on top of my android app/game screen ?

For example see this picture :

[image]

There are some game hack applications that when hackers try to use them , their icons appear on top of other app / game screens and then they can abuse and hack the game items.

I want to know is there any way to detect if another button or icon is top of my game screen ?

With java native code or something else ?

Comment: I don't think you could do that, at least until you have maximum privileges like admin / device owner.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a conditional check like so

```
var isFabOpen = false;
function fabTap(args) {
   var fab = args.object;
   var button = page.getViewById('btna');
   var button2 = page.getViewById('btnb');
   if (isFabOpen === true) 

       isFabOpen = false; //close active fab so you can open the new button i.e button.scaleX 1.5 so it grows bigger or change border colour
button2.blah blah blah! Your code to open button2 or any button or view

     } else {

       isFabOpen = true;
  }
exports.fabTap = fabTap;

function closeFab(args){
  isFabOpen = false; // obvious

}
exports.closeFab=closeFab;
```